# Instagram Media-ID

Tags: android, api

I have the Instagram Comment Endpoints. And I wanted to get a list of recent comments on a media object. But in the GET Link: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`
They have the Media-ID, but I don't know how to get randomly media-id from user?
How to get the Media-ID ?

Comment: Read the documentation full to get the media list, there are other API's to get the file lists.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: https://goo.gl/56BXLg here is an API to get the users self media lists. so, here you can get the media id's.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply @Nigam, but this is self id right?. What I mean is where can i get one randomly from random users ?

Comment: Basically please go through the documentation properly, in that page only there are some functionality, you can check.